# comparing image src jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a game where there are 12 cards turned upside down. When you click on a card it flips over with an image there are 2 of every image so a total of 6 images on 12 cards. the point is to match those images. I am having trouble comparing if the img src are the same of the flipped images here is what i have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/LbcHf/1/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
</div>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Play again">
</form>
```

Comment: And where are the images?

Comment: They're generated in the javascript. All he needs to do is store the last image clicked, and check against the current one.

Comment: @David Thomas yea they are all in the array images its better to look at the jsfiddle than the actual code i put up you'll understand it a lot better

Comment: You may have missed the point of posting code in the question if we have to look at the JS Fiddle demo to understand what's going on.

Comment: @remyabel yes you are correct you have any idea how you could help me with my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script should look like this:

```
var lastSelected;
$(document).ready(function(){
    addImg();
    start();
    click();
});

function check(el){
    if($(lastSelected).attr("src") == $(el).find("img").attr("src") && $(lastSelected).hasClass("visible")) {
            // do sth. with $(this)
            alert("gotcha!");
    }
    lastSelected = $(el).find("img");
}

function start(){
    $("div.row div img").addClass("hidden");
};

function click(){
    $("div.row div").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
         if($("img", this).hasClass("hidden")){
            $("img",this).removeClass("hidden");
            $("img",this).addClass("visible");
             check($(this));

         }else if($("img",this).hasClass("visible")){
            $("img",this).removeClass("visible");
            $("img",this).addClass("hidden");
         }

        });

    });

};

function addImg (){

    var images = ["http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/cheese.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/eggs.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/kitchen_blender.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/tea.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/kitchen_collander.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/kitchen_teapot.gif"];

var imagesused = [];
$('.container div:not(.row)').each(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    $(this).append('<img src="' + images[rand] + '"/>');
    if (imagesused.indexOf(images[rand]) != -1) images.splice(rand, 1);
    else imagesused.push(images[rand]);
    console.log(images);

});
}
```

Comment: although your variable imgSrc is not specific set, so you have to do it a bit different... my code just looks for img's with the same src, as you asked here.

Comment: didnt work i need to compare the 2 most recently flipped cards this unfortunetly doesnt do that

Comment: wait a second, I think I know what you want to do, I'll edit the post above - finished editing

Comment: Thanks but its still not working right i think its not the check function but maybe my previous code that is not allowing for us to check the img src of the two flipped cards

Comment: In your fiddle, you only called check once. You need to add it to your click function, or move the code there.

Comment: yes you are not really comparing the last two flipped cards, but all.. I'll try to change your Fiddle, that it will work. Just give me some minutes :)

Comment: Why would you need such a verbose solution? All you need is a simple check as I provided in my answer.

Comment: Finally I got it, @remyabel yes the check is easy but the rest of code was wrong..

Comment: thank you sir and what did you change in the previous code that was incorrect?

Comment: glad I could help. 1. it was wrong that check() was called from the document's ready function, it had to be called like `check($(this));` from the click function. 2. you had to store the last selected image, so you can compare it.

Answer (score 1):

I am taking the same jQuery lesson at O'reilly School online http://www.oreillyschool.com

The answer to this is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmccommas/AhPfV/

jquery code to use

```
 var lastSelected;
    var score = 0;
    var boxopened = "";
    var imgopened = "";
    var num = 0;
    var moves = 0;
    $(function () {
        $("div.row div img").addClass('hidden');
        addImg();
        click();
        check();
        shuffle();


    });

    function randomFromTo(from, to) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    }

    function shuffle() {
        var children = $("#boxcard").children();
        var child = $("#boxcard div:first-child");

        var array_img = new Array();

        for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            array_img[i] = $("#" + child.attr("id") + " img").attr("src");
            child = child.next();
        }

        var child = $("#boxcard div:first-child");

        for (z = 0; z < children.length; z++) {
            randIndex = randomFromTo(0, array_img.length - 1);

            // set new image
            $("#" + child.attr("id") + " img").attr("src", array_img[randIndex]);
            array_img.splice(randIndex, 1);

            child = child.next();
        }
    }


    function check(el) {

        if ($(lastSelected).attr("src") == $(el).find("img").attr("src") && $(lastSelected).hasClass("visible")) {
            score = 0 + 2;
            alert("Congradulation! You scored!!" + " " + score + " Points");
        }

        lastSelected = $(el).find("img");
        clearAll();

    }


    function click() {

        var boxes = $(".row img").size();
        $(".row div").click(function () {
            moves++;
            $(".totalmoves").html(moves);
            $(".cover").css({
                "z-index": "9999"
            });
            $(this).children("img").animate({
                "opacity": "1"
            }, function () {
                num++;
                var id1 = $("img.selected").attr("src");
                var id2 = $(this).attr("src");
                $(this).addClass("selected");

                if (num == 2) {
                    num = 0;
                    if (id1 == id2) {
                        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                        score = score + 2;
                        alert("Congradulation! You scored!!" + " " + score + " Points");
                        boxes = boxes - 2;
                        if (boxes == 0) {
                            alert("Game Over Your Total Score is :" + score + " Points");
                        }

                        $(".yourscore").html(score);
                    } else {
                        speed = 100;
                        $(".selected").animate({
                            "opacity": "0"
                        }, 400, function () {
                            $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                            if (score > 1) {
                                score = score - 0.5;
                                $(".yourscore").html(score);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    speed = 100;
                }

                $(this).animate({
                    "padding": "0.1"
                }, speed, function () {
                    $(".cover").css({
                        "z-index": "-9999"
                    });
                });
            });

        });


    };

    // add Random Images
    function addImg() {

        var images = ["http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/cheese.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/eggs.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/kitchen_blender.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/tea.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/kitchen_collander.gif", "http://courses.oreillyschool.com/jquery/QuizzesAndProjects/images/kitchen_teapot.gif"];

        var imagesused = [];
        $('.container div:not(.row)').each(function () {
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
            $(this).append('<img src="' + images[rand] + '"/>');
            if (imagesused.indexOf(images[rand]) != -1) images.splice(rand, 1);
            else imagesused.push(images[rand]);
            console.log(images);

        });
    }
    // Clear the images Button
    var clearAll = function () {
        $(':button').click(function () {
            score = 0;
            $(".yourscore").html(score);
            moves = 0;
            $(".totalmoves").html(moves);
            $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
            $(".row img").animate({
                "opacity": "0"
            }, function () {
                $(".row img").remove();
                addImg();

            });




        });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
function check(){
    $('img.visible:not(.correct):eq(0)').attr('src') == $('img.visible:not(.correct):eq(1)').attr('src'))){
        $('img.visible:not(.correct)').addClass('correct')
    }
}
```

So if to cards are turned and they are both the same you add a `class` to them so they won't get checked again next time. So this way you would only check the two cards that you just turned.

Comment: thanks and yea i created a class of done if they are both correct however this is still not working but like i mentioned before it might be my other functions that are making this check function so hard

Answer (score 0):

As you have your code right now, it requires some refactoring. But to answer your immediate question, it's this simple:

```
var last;
function click(){
    $("div.row div").each(function(){
         // ..snip..

             // added code
             console.log(last == $("img",this).attr("src"));
             last = $("img",this).attr("src");
```

The reason why I won't go into more detail is because I'd assume that you only want two cards to be face up at a time, so there is no reason to loop through all the visible cards.

Comment: yes that is true but the only visible cards or img that have class visible are the cards that are flipped up

Comment: i tried this and didnt get the result i was looking for maybe i did it wrong